# Creating New PHP Project Via Aptana

Tags: php, html, error-handling, project, aptana

Every time I try to start a new PHP project I get the following message:

"Creation Problems:

Internal error."

It shows that the location via wamp (C:\wamp\www\class412\lab5) is empty.

Has anyone had this problem or is there a solution?

Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a question for Aptana support

Answer (score 0):

If the location **is not** empty, try *import* by right clicking on the *Project explorer* panel instead of *New > PHP Project*.

---

@Machavity: I think you maybe should reconsider closing any question related to Aptana, seeing that the *former* [official support is now closed](https://aptanastudio.tenderapp.com/) and that Aptana seems to [redirect support questions to Stack Overflow](http://www.aptana.com/support.html).